Flutter just_audio is not playing the stream audio
If i get all of the bytes at once from the API and pass it to just_audio it works fine, but that takes time, so i decided to get data in chunks from the API and keep passing it to just_audio and start playing the audio without any delay.
But it seems like there is some issue there.
This is my controller code, which keeps adding bytes to the CustomSource.
But it does not play any audio.
await for (var chunk in res!) {

  if(isFirstChunkSend == false) {
    customSource = MyCustomSource();
    customSource.addBytes(chunk);
    audioData.addAll(chunk);
    player.setAudioSource(customSource);

    isFirstChunkSend = true;

  }else {
   customSource.addBytes(chunk);
  }

In my widget i have created MyCustomSource class.
class MyCustomSource extends StreamAudioSource {
  final StreamController<List<int>> _controller = StreamController<List<int>>.broadcast();
  List<int> bytes = [];
  bool isClosed = false;

  MyCustomSource() {
    _controller.stream.listen((chunk) {
      bytes.addAll(chunk);
     // print("Bytes added, total length: ${bytes.length}");
    }, onDone: () {
      isClosed = true;
      print("Stream closed");
    });
  }

  void addBytes(List<int> chunk) {
    if (!isClosed) {
      _controller.add(chunk);
      print("Bytes added: ${bytes}");
    }
  }

  void complete() {
    if (!isClosed) {
      _controller.close();
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<StreamAudioResponse> request([int? start, int? end]) async {
    start ??= 0;
    end ??= bytes.length;
    
    final initialBytes = bytes.sublist(start, end);
    
    Stream<List<int>> byteStream = _controller.stream
        .transform(StreamTransformer.fromHandlers(
      handleData: (chunk, sink) {
        if (start! < bytes.length) {
          end ??= bytes.length;
          int? chunkEnd = end! < bytes.length ? end : bytes.length;
          sink.add(bytes.sublist(start!, chunkEnd));
          start = chunkEnd;
        } else {
          sink.close();
        }
      },
    ));
    
    return StreamAudioResponse(
      sourceLength: bytes.length,
      contentLength: end! - start!,
      offset: start,
      stream: byteStream,
      contentType: 'audio/mpeg',
    );
  }
}


may this correction help you buddy to resolve issues related to streaming audio in chunks and playing it using just_audio.
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';

class MyCustomSource extends StreamAudioSource {
  final StreamController<List<int>> _controller = StreamController<List<int>>.broadcast();
  List<int> bytes = [];
  bool isClosed = false;

  MyCustomSource() {
    _controller.stream.listen((chunk) {
      bytes.addAll(chunk);
    }, onDone: () {
      isClosed = true;
    });
  }

  void addBytes(List<int> chunk) {
    if (!isClosed) {
      _controller.add(chunk);
    }
  }

  void complete() {
    if (!isClosed) {
      _controller.close();
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<StreamAudioResponse> request([int? start, int? end]) async {
    start ??= 0;
    end ??= bytes.length;

    final initialBytes = bytes.sublist(start, end);

    // Transform the stream to only send the requested chunk
    Stream<List<int>> byteStream = _controller.stream.transform(
      StreamTransformer<List<int>, List<int>>.fromHandlers(
        handleData: (chunk, sink) {
          if (start! < bytes.length) {
            int chunkEnd = end! < bytes.length ? end : bytes.length;
            sink.add(bytes.sublist(start, chunkEnd));
            start = chunkEnd;
          } else {
            sink.close();
          }
        },
        handleError: (error, stackTrace, sink) {
          // Handle errors if any
          sink.addError(error, stackTrace);
        },
        handleDone: (sink) {
          sink.close();
        },
      ),
    );

    return StreamAudioResponse(
      sourceLength: bytes.length,
      contentLength: end - start,
      offset: start,
      stream: byteStream,
      contentType: 'audio/mpeg',
    );
  }
}

I've updated the transform method to use StreamTransformer<List, List>.fromHandlers instead of StreamTransformer.fromHandlers. This ensures that the transformation correctly handles lists of integers (bytes) as both input and output.
